# Too many arguments to function call, What do I do?

Tags: c, macos, function, argument-passing, function-calls

I am working on a problem in my textbook and I need to make a triangle angle calculator Im used to java but Im not 100% on C yet, I don't understand the logic in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static float angleB;
static float angleA;

float remainingAngle(float answer)
{
    float answer= angleA+angleB;
//redefinition of answer
 return 0;
}
//CANT TOUCH FROM HERE TO END
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float angleA = 30.0;
    float angleB = 60.0;
    float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA,angleB);
// to many arguments to function call (referring to angleC)
    printf("the third angle is %.2f\n",angleC);
    return 0;
}     //END CANT TOUCH
```

I don't know what to do here.

Comment: `What do I do?`--> provide correct number of arguments . Period.

Comment: Too many arguments for remainingAngle, not printf.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'float angleA = 30.0;'   The variable 'angleA' is declared as float, so the initialization value needs to also be declared as float;   Suggest: 'float angleA = 30.0f;'   Note the trailing 'f'.   The posted code is using a 'double' initializer (the default when a decimal point in the initializer is double, unless specifically declared otherwise via the trailing 'f')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function definition

```
float remainingAngle(float answer)
```

the function `remainingAngle()` accepts one parameter.

OTOH, in your function call

```
remainingAngle(angleA,angleB);
```

you're passing two arguments.

The supplied argument number and type should match with the parameter list in function definition.

---

That said, your code is wrong.

- **Point 1.** Your local variables will *shadow* the global ones. Maybe that's not what you want. Change

  ```
  float angleA = 30.0;
  float angleB = 60.0;
  ```

  to

  ```
   angleA = 30.0;
   angleB = 60.0;
  ```
- **Point 2.**  The function

  ```
  float remainingAngle(float answer)
  {
      float answer= angleA+angleB;
  //redefinition of answer
   return 0;
  }
  ```

  is logically wrong. It should rather be

  ```
  float remainingAngle(void)
  {
      float answer= angleA+angleB;
      return answer;
  }
  ```

  and should be called like

  ```
  float angleC = remainingAngle();
  ```

---

AFTER EDIT:

as per your requirement,  you can do

```
float remainingAngle(float angleA, float angleB)
{
    float answer= angleA+angleB;
    return answer;
}
```

However, this makes the global variables useless.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Souravs answer you could also do the following:

```
float remainingAngle(float angA, float angB)
{
    float answer = angA + angB;
    return answer;
}
```

So your call will stay the same.

And for the logical side, what you do is:

You pass two arguments (value of `angleA` and value of `angleB`) to the function `remainingAngle`. There you do the calculation and return the result (`answer`).

Comment: You're right, but in this case, `angleA` and `angleB`  being global, it's not required to be passed as parameters. :-)

Comment: I know, I just wrote it like this in case the variables are not global. Then he also knows what's going on.

Comment: I think I got it, I took your suggestion, removed the static floats, and changed the return function to "180-answer" this way the angle is inversely related to the increase in a+b"

Answer (score 0):

The design of your function isn't good:

```
static float angleB;
static float angleA;

float remainingAngle(float answer)
{
    float answer= angleA+angleB;
//redefinition of answer
 return 0;
}
```

> What do I do?

- There's no point is passing in the answer; the answer is what you want to receive. (There's also no point in passing "space"  for the answer. The anser is a `float`, a scalar variable. Just pass that around.) **Remove the `answer` argument.**
- You redefine `answer` as local variable. After removing the argument of the same name, that redefinition goes away. But in that case you should return `answer` instead of `0`. You could even do without the intermediary variable `answer` and return the result expression. So: **Return the desired expression**
- The answer depends on two global variables. The function should work on two angles that you pass as arguments. **Provide two angle arguments to your function and remove the global variables.**
- And finally, the sum of the three angles in a triangle is 180°, so your remaining angle calculation is wrong.

Putting all that together:

```
float remainingAngle(float a, float b)
{
    return 180.0f - a - b;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA, angleB);
```

> Im used to java

I'm not too familiar with Java, but I don't think functios on scalars like this one are fundamentally different in C and Java.